# oracle select with IN form another tables field

Tags: oracle, select

I have a table named `departments` with columns-

```
id number(10)
description varchar2(20)
```

And a configuration table called `filters` with columns-

```
filtername varchar2(10)
filter varchar2(20)
```

The `filter` column should contain a list of id's that should be used as filter in the `where` clause e.g. '10,20,30'

```
select * 
 from departments
    , filters 
where filters.filtername='MYFILTE' 
  and departments in filters.filter
```

I can only use one record per filter. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
 from departments d 
where id in (select regexp_substr(filter,'[^,]+', 1, level) from filters
               where filtername='MYFILTE' --use this line if you only want to use one filter, remove if you want to apply all filters
             connect by regexp_substr(filter, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null);
```

A table like this -

```
create table filters (filter varchar2(100), filtername varchar2(20));
```

With data like this-

```
insert into filters values ('10,20,30','Filter1');
insert into filters values ('40,50,60','Filter2');
```

Run the query like this (assuming column `filter` has values separated by `,`)-

```
select distinct regexp_substr(filter,'[^,]+', 1, level) from filters
connect by regexp_substr(filter, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
order by 1;
```

Returns this-

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(FILTER,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL)
-----------------------------------------
10
20
30
40
50
60
```

Note- Neither the `distinct` nor the `order by` matters in your case (i.e. not required in your query, but you can use them anyway).

Comment: exactly what I was searchin for. Thank you very much. My filters table has many records so I use the with statement to filter out the record I wanted and the used this alias in your select. This speeds up the query extremely

Comment: wow, very cool use of connect by to simulate "explode" without having to use a function. +1

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved by a simple join :)

```
select * 
from departments d
join filters f on d.description = f.filter
where f.filtername='MYFILTE'
```

edit: I missed that f.filter was a comma separated string with values
In that case there are 2 options:

use LIKE:

```
select * 
from departments d
join filters f on f.filter like '%'||d.description||'%'
where f.filtername='MYFILTE'
```

or use your own explode function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DM.varchar_list_type as table of varchar2(255);

CREATE OR REPLACE function explode(p_separator in varchar2, p_string in varchar2)
return varchar_list_type 
as
   l_string   varchar2(4000) default p_string || p_separator;
   l_data     varchar_list_type := varchar_list_type();
   n          number;
begin
   loop
      exit when l_string is null;
      n := instr (l_string, p_separator);
      l_data.extend;
      l_data (l_data.count) := ltrim (rtrim (substr (l_string, 1, n - 1)));
      l_string := substr (l_string, n + 1);
   end loop;

   return l_data;
-- no exception. I want to see the error messages (for now at least)
end;

select * 
from departments d
join filters f on d.description in (table(explode(',', f.filter)))
where f.filtername='MYFILTE'
```

Comment: Think you missed that the `filter` column is a single string with comma-seperated values, not one row per value, so this won't match.